# i want show an image in a triangle using css

Tags: html, css

```
<img class="triangle" src="image.png"/>
```

CSS

```
.triangle{
??}
```

Now I want to apply `css` to the triangle `class` to show the image in a triangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made you a fiddle here. You need to wrapp your image with a div to do what you want:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r5Lj1a1y/3/).

```css
.triangle{
    position: relative;
}
.triangle:before{
    border-top: 0;
    border-right: 190px solid white;
    border-bottom: 240px solid transparent;
    border-left: 170px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class='triangle'>
    <img src="http://s.hswstatic.com/gif/landscape-photography-1.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how and why this works? It's a very good solution, I'd love to understand why this works though?

Comment: @patrick, there is not that much explaining to it. Using borders you can create different shapes, like triangles in the above example. `:before` pseudo element makes it easy to place the borders above the `.triangle` element by also making use of `relative` and `absolute` positioning. You can see more examples of shapes here https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/